# WCF - OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal is null

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, wcf-security

In the last project, i implementation **AuthenticationManager** and **AuthorizationManager** services in **WCF** also configuration the project.

I can access to Identity in Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity but OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal is null.

How i can set data and access the OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal object.